# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I am trying to get my first WordPress installation running under Windows IIS 7.5 and I am running into the common "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress." error.

I used the Web Matrix Installer which installed:
PHP 5.3.19
Wordpress 3.4
MySQL 5.1

I have run the PHPinfo.php page with no problems so I know PHP is working.

The MySQL service is running (though I'm not sure how to test that it is actually working).

Presumably WordPress is installed properly but cannot "speak" to mySQL. I have tried the following from other articles about this same error:

1. Changed the hosts file so the IPv6 is commented out, like so,

   127.0.0.1 localhost

   ## ::1 localhost

Restarted IIS afterwards. Rebooted as well.

1. Made sure that extension=php_mysql.dll and extension=php_mysqli.dll are uncommented in my php.ini file
2. Granted IIS_IUSRS and NETWORK SERVICE permissions to the entire WP directory and the PHP directory.
3. Confirmed that an environment variable had been created which points to the PHP installation directory, which is C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\

FYI I am running this on a Amazon EC2 instance of windows 2008R2 if that matters.

Any help would be appreciated - this is driving me a little crazy at this point and I cannot find any other suggestions.

Comment: phpinfo() and see if mysql exist

Comment: is php_mysql.dll and php_mysqli.dll installed in the correct locations?

Comment: sorry for the delay I have been pulled away from this for some time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there ware two problems in my php.ini.
First the extension_dir was not set (as i run on Windows I just had to uncomment the default 'ext' line).
Second the dll's for mqsql was not enabled.
Same here, I just uncommented the two lines and after restarting the World Wide Web Publishing Service it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Another common reason for this error is because the extensions directory is commented or is not properly set in your php.ini ( php.ini-production comes with 2 settings, both commented out). Open your php.ini. and do a search for extension_dir. Uncomment the appropriate line depending on your OS (on Windows the ext dir is "ext") and restart your web service.

Answer (score -1):

I put PHP in c:\PHP. I have added C:\PHP and C:\PHP\ext into my PATH env variable. Therefore, there is not necessary to copy all dll's from C:\PHP and C:\PHP\ext  into C:\windows\system32